# How do I adjust font size in VS Code markdown preview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

The entirety of my Visual Studio Code `settings.json` file is:

```
{
    "notebook.markup.fontSize": 48,
}
```

I can create a markdown file eg `file.md` and preview it in VS Code by pressing the following key combination:

```
Ctrl+K V
```

This markdown preview font is too small for my taste. Adjusting it [like this article recommends](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_notebooks) does nothing. I don't have any extensions installed. To demonstrate how I adjust the setting I could use either of these two `settings.json` files and the markdown preview font size remains constant.

*`settings.json` file #1*

```
{
    "notebook.markup.fontSize": 12,
}
```

*`settings.json` file #2*

```
{
    "notebook.markup.fontSize": 48,
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Cant you just use "command +" to increase the font size? Or Control + on a windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably be using the setting:

```
Markdown > Preview: Font Size
```

It doesn't sound like you are in a Notebook since you are using that command to preview it.

Comment: That is the solution, I placed `"markdown.preview.fontSize": 48` into my `settings.json` and now everything works as expected.

Comment: `Markdown > Preview: Font Size` is available in the settings UI now. Just search for Font Size and scroll down.